# List is not displayed when using *ngSwitchCase

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

I want to bind 3 buttons to 3 different lists. I could use `ion-segment`but since I like the design over the segments I just do it with custom buttons. But now when I implement the *ngSwitchCase the lists are simply not displayed when I click on a button and I get this error  `Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute`

## page.html

```
 <ion-row [(ngModel)]="pre" [(ngModel)]="type" class="bg">
            <ion-col col-4><ion-button value="own"</ion-button></ion-col>
            <ion-col col-4><ion-button value="friends"</ion-button></ion-col>
            <ion-col col-4><ion-button value="all" </ion-button></ion-col>
          </ion-row>

 <div [ngSwitch]="pre">
      
    <ion-list  *ngSwitchCase="'own'">
   
     </ion-list>

       <ion-list  *ngSwitchCase="'friends'">
   
     </ion-list>

       <ion-list  *ngSwitchCase="'all'">
 
     </ion-list>
   
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue here is that `ion-row` doesn't implement value accessor, which is required for using `ngModel`, you need to use an element that does implement value accessor.

for instance `ion-segment`

```
  <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="type" [(ngModel)]="pre">    
    <ion-segment-button value="own">
      Own
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="friends">
      Friends
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="all">
      All
    </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
```

it's weird to have two ngModels on one element, but you can if you'd like.